# Returning to initial frame after creating new frame using tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have created a simple GUI that has two buttons. When the 'Check Info' button is clicked, a new frame is created and overlaid over the initial frame. This new frame has a 'Return Home button'. What I want to do is destroy the Check Info frame and return back to the initial frame. Could someone point me in the right direction?

I got this far by following the tutorial at http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Gui(Tk):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        initframe = ttk.Frame(self, padding="3 3 12 12")
        initframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        initframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        initframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.resizable(False, False)


        ttk.Button(initframe, text="Check Info", command=self.check_info).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
        ttk.Button(initframe, text="Run Tests" ).grid(column=4, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

        for child in initframe.winfo_children():
            child.grid_configure(padx=20, pady=20)

        self.update()
        self.geometry(self.geometry())

        self.bind('<Return>', self.check_info_enter)

    def goback(self):
        self.destroy()

    def check_info(self):
        info_frame = ttk.Frame(self, padding="3 3 12 12")
        info_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        info_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        info_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.resizable(False, False)

        ttk.Button(info_frame, text="Return Home", command=self.goback).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))


    def check_info_enter(self, event):
        self.update()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Gui(None)
    app.title('Initial')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `goback()` is going to destroy the root window, (which is `self` in this instance), you probably want to store the created frame (`info_frame`) as an instance variable and destroy *that* inside of `go_back()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Replace every occurrence of `info_frame` with `self.info_frame`.  This will make the frame accessible through `self`.
2. Inside `goback`, replace `self.destroy()` with `self.info_frame.destroy()`.  Doing this will make the method destroy the `Check Info` frame and not the main window.

Below is a version of your script that does this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Gui(Tk):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        initframe = ttk.Frame(self, padding="3 3 12 12")
        initframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        initframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        initframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.resizable(False, False)


        ttk.Button(initframe, text="Check Info", command=self.check_info).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
        ttk.Button(initframe, text="Run Tests" ).grid(column=4, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

        for child in initframe.winfo_children():
            child.grid_configure(padx=20, pady=20)

        self.update()
        self.geometry(self.geometry())

        self.bind('<Return>', self.check_info_enter)

    def goback(self):
        self.info_frame.destroy()

    def check_info(self):
        self.info_frame = ttk.Frame(self, padding="3 3 12 12")
        self.info_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        self.info_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.info_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.resizable(False, False)

        ttk.Button(self.info_frame, text="Return Home", command=self.goback).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))


    def check_info_enter(self, event):
        self.update()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Gui(None)
    app.title('Initial')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This works like an absolute charm, thank you! One odd behavior I noticed: If I create and destroy the info_frame a lot, occasionally the python app will minimize. Is there a way I can prevent that happening?

Comment: @J.Robertson - I'm having a hard time duplicating this behavior (I created/destroyed the frame dozens of times without it).  If I had to guess, you are double-clicking the main window when you are doing this.  Some systems are set up to have this minimize the window.  Perhaps yours is?

Comment: Nope, no double clicking - I'm making i am just single clicking on the button once. It's very odd. I will click the Check Info button, then the Return Home Button...Then, if I hit the Check Info button again, SOMETIMES it will minimize the app...its very odd.